# GridFS put() with Mongoose dies in write concern code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs

I have the following code (trimmed, assume all the closing stuff is there), which dies deep down inside GridFS:

```
var Grid = require('mongodb').Grid;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/ksnap');

router.route('/').post(function(req, res) {

    var post = new Post();
    var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });

    req.pipe(busboy);

    busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {

        console.log('File [' + fieldname + ']: filename: ' + filename + ', encoding: ' + encoding + ', mimetype: ' + mimetype);
        if (fieldname != 'img') { return; }

        var bufs = [];

        file.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] got ' + data.length + ' bytes');

            bufs.push(data);

        }); // busboy file on data

        file.on('end', function() {
            console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] Finished');

            var buf = Buffer.concat(bufs);

            var grid = new Grid(db, 'fs');
            grid.put(buf, {metadata:{category:'image'}, content_type: 'image'}, function(err, result) {
                if (err) { console.log(err); } else { console.log(result); }
            });
```

Stack trace:

```
/opt/ksnap-server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/gridfs/gridstore.js:1552
  } else if(self.safe.w != null || typeof self.safe.j == 'boolean' || typeof s
                     ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'w' of undefined
    at _getWriteConcern (/opt/ksnap-server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/gridfs/gridstore.js:1552:22)
    at Stream.GridStore (/opt/ksnap-server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/gridfs/gridstore.js:100:23)
    at Grid.put (/opt/ksnap-server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/gridfs/grid.js:52:19)
    at FileStream.<anonymous> (/opt/ksnap-server/server.js:83:13)
    at FileStream.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:943:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

Busboy returns a stream which I put into a buffer, so far so good. This works fine, I've tested it. But when I try to grid.put() the buffer, it dies as above. I've tried to trace it, but I'm having trouble. <s>As far as I can tell, the all the options get eaten in grid.js, so by the time they get passed down to gridstore.js it's just an empty object.</s> Mongoose just doesn't set this, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get past this error by manually setting `db.safe = {w: 1};` after opening the connection, however when I did the `grid.put()` it just stuck there. Swapping out mongoose for a regular mongodb connection worked, so I guess currently mongoose just doesn't work with GridFS.

I was finally able to get everything (apparently) working by adding the [streamifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/streamifier) and [gridfs-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gridfs-stream) modules, and the following mongo setup:

```
var streamifier = require('streamifier');
var Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/ksnap');
```

Then later, when I'm ready to save the file to GridFS:

```
var gfs = new Grid(mongoose.connection.db, mongoose.mongo);
var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({
    mode: 'w',
    filename: post.id,
    content_type: 'image/jpeg'
});
streamifier.createReadStream(buffer).pipe(writestream);
writestream.on('close', function (file) {
    console.log("saved 300px as "+file.filename);
});
```

And save the post document itself to MongoDB:

```
post.save(function(err) {
    if (err) { res.send(err); }
    console.log('saved post '+post.id);
    res.send(post);
});
```

This was the combination of options that worked for me. One of the keys was using `mongoose.connect()`, not `mongoose.createConnection()`, which would let me save the files, but not the documents.

Answer (score -1):

I know this has been a while - I saw the same issue - make sure your mongoose session is connected to the DB - ie 
`mongoose.connection.once("connected", function () {...}` has been called, then load the require files and files. This ensures the db object in the connection is bound to an existing mongo session. If you find the `mongoose.connection.db` is null and `mongoose.connection` is NOT null then you will have initialized your grid stream with an uninitialized mongodb connection.